# The sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ should be 1, not zero

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the sum

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$$

I tried solving this telescopic series by taking its limit after rewriting the series as follows: distributing $n$ into the parenthesis and later dividing both numerator and denominator by the highest exponential of $n$, in this case $n^2$ (as shown below).

$$\frac{1}{n(n+1)} = \frac{1}{n^2+n} = \frac{\frac{1}{n^2}}{1+\frac{1}{n}}$$

As $n \rightarrow \infty$, $1/n^2$ and $1/n$ go to $0$,

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{0}{1+0} = 0$$

Thus, the limit should be equal to zero, but this is wrong (by partial fraction decomposition I get 1). The problem is that I cannot tell why this way of solving is wrong. Any insights?

Comment: You just showed that the nth term of the series tends to 0 for very large values of n. In your solution that you show, you haven’t done anything about the sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you're looking at

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$

and claimed that the value is

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \text{ instead of } \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n a_i$$

This should immediately be questionable logic to you. For instance, for the easier geometric series, $a_n = (1/2)^n$,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} = 1 \text{ but } \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2^n} = 0$$

and there are any number of ways to see this. (For instance, $1/2^n> 0$ for all $n \ge 1$. So summing up a bunch of them should give you a positive number.)

---

Moreover, it can be said that this argument is somewhat futile, because, if the summation $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges in the first place, then automatically $a_n \to 0$.

However, it is also worth noting that this is not a sufficient condition, since the harmonic series ($a_n = 1/n$) famously diverges, despite $a_n \to 0$. You need the limit to be zero, but that is not enough, in other words.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. It is a trivial mistake, but either way I was trapped in it. I somehow thought that the sum of a infinite series could be found by taking its limit (somewhat the limit of a sequence), what is entirely wrong.